# Which is the best way to update table data after Ajax form submit to show updated table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the Table with rows and  when I click on add button the Light Box shows the form to add the row.

Now I want to show the newly added row to table and I have two options

1. refresh the whole table so that all the small buttons like `edit/delete' also gets added to the row
2. Only add the new row. This is good but then again I have to add the edit/delete logic in the template and attach the events to it.

Which way should I go?

Comment: always adding a row would be good rather pulling entire data.
CODE: $("table > tbody").prepend(get the updated/created row from ajax); and for delete just find the closest tr and fadeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.delegate` or `.on` rather than attach events to all small buttons in the table. And then you do not need to attach the events each time you add a row.
Something like

```
$("#table_id").on("click","button.edit",function(){
    //edit the row
}).on("click","button.delete",function(){
    //delete the row
});
```

Have a look at [jquery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)